# How can I download tick data from Bloomberg using the xbbg python library?

Tags: python, bloomberg, trading

I am trying to download tick data from Bloomberg using the python xbbg library. By tick data, I mean that a new line of info is generated every time there is a change in the bid or ask volume/price, or there is a trade. I have added a sample of the target output below.

Can someone please assist by provide some sample code to download the data?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code.

The function is a generator, yielding every tick as `dict` of data from Bloomberg.

You need to include it in your signal processing backend to make this useful.

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp
In [2]: cnt = 0
In [3]: for t in blp.live('QQQ US Equity', flds=['Bid', 'Ask', 'Last_Price']):
            cnt += 1
            print(t)
            if cnt > 10: break
{'TICKER': 'QQQ US Equity', 'MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE': 'SUMMARY', 'MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE': 'INITPAINT', 'BID': 185.23, 'ASK': 185.24, 'BEST_BID': 184.72, 'BEST_ASK': 184.74, 'BID_ALL_SESSION': 184.72, 'ASK_ALL_SESSION': 184.74, ....}
```

Another method to download historical tick data is below.
The problem is, **sometimes it returns empty DataFrame**.
Still not sure what's happening - maybe solve this later.

```
In [4]: blp.bdtick('QQQ US Equity', dt='2020-03-30').tail()
                          QQQ US Equity
                                    typ  value volume cond exch
2020-03-31 20:00:00-04:00         TRADE 190.31      0   OC    C
2020-03-31 20:00:00-04:00         TRADE 190.30      0   OC    B
2020-03-31 20:00:00-04:00         TRADE 190.21      0   OC    A
2020-03-31 20:00:00-04:00         TRADE 190.43      0   OC    D
2020-03-31 20:00:00-04:00         TRADE 190.40      0   CC    Q
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The blp.bdtick('QQQ US Equity', dt='2020-03-30').tail() line only downloads trades - do you know how to get the bid and ask prices/volumes as well (same as the sample of data above)?

Comment: You can try blp.bdtick('QQQ US Equity', types=['BID', 'ASK', 'TRADE'], dt='2020-03-30'), where types can be str or list. Lots of the time this returns empty DataFrame for me. Wonder if this is Bloomberg issue or xbbg.

Comment: `timeout` argument is added in the updated version of 0.7.0b1. If everything works fine within couple of days will release 0.7.0 later.